# What "motor" revs up just before EVE takes the plant?

Tags: wall-e

When Wall-E shows EVE the plant, it sounds like some sort of motor revs up, then EVE opens her chest, takes the plant, shuts down, then turns off Wall-E's electronics. What is the "motor" that revs up in this scene?

Comment: For reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cguHMPgDvI

Comment: Nothing useful in the [script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Wall-E.html); [EVE] Drops the lighter.
          In a flash...
          ...her chest opens...
          ...a TRACTOR BEAM snatches the plant away...
          ...stores it inside her...
          Then she shuts down completely.
          Only a SINGLE GREEN LIGHT pulsing on her chest.

Comment: Nothing useful in the [novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3359002-wall-e-disney-pixar-wall-e) "*EVE’s blue light immediately locked onto it. Her chest opened. WALL·E was shocked to see a tractor beam suddenly shoot from EVE’s chest and envelop the plant. The beam had pulled the plant into a compartment in EVE’s chest. Her panel doors slammed, and her system shut down altogether! Only a single green light remained pulsing on her chest.*"

Comment: It’s not just an emotive sound like R2D2 might emit? No need for there to be a motor to make that sound.

Comment: @ToddWilcox After the "motor" revs up, it seems like its spinning very fast until EVE shuts down, in which the "motor" shuts off.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of gas turbine,  (or a ducted fan)  She's clearly causing some sort of power surge in all of the things that Wall-E has collected so it could be anything in his trailer/anything he's collected in the time he's been tidying up.  Or maybe his tracked home was originally powered by a turbine engine and that's what you can hear spinning?